# Trying to write test pgm for TimeSync

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: changed code according to ans. Still will not compile.

```
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>


using namespace message_filters;

class SynchronizerTest
{
public:
  SynchronizerTest()
  {
    setTest();
  }


void handelerSynchronizerTest(geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& msg1, geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& msg2)
{
    ROS_INFO("HERE made it to handeler");
}

void setTest()
{
     Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> j1_sub(n, "/SynchronizerTest1", 10);
     Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> j2_sub(n, "/SynchronizerTest2", 10);
     TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> sync(j1_sub, j2_sub, 10);
     sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&SynchronizerTest::handelerSynchronizerTest, this, _1, _2));
     ROS_INFO("Test set");
}


private:

 ros::NodeHandle n;

};  // Enodof Class



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "SynchronizerTest");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  int count = 0;

  SynchronizerTest sp;
  ros::Publisher pub1 = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("SynchronizerTest1", 10);
  ros::Publisher pub2 = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("SynchronizerTest2", 10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
     geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;     
     msg.header.stamp = ros::time::now();
     pub1.publish(msg);
     pub2.publish(msg);
     ros::spinOnce();
     loop_rate.sleep();
     ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Trying to write test pgm for TimeSync but why does it not support std_msgs:String.

```
/opt/ros/hydro/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h:126:102: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘ros::message_traits::TimeStamp<std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >, void>’
```

This compile error is generated by the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>


using namespace message_filters;

class SynchronizerTest
{
public:
  SynchronizerTest()
  {
    setTest();
  }


void handelerSynchronizerTest(std_msgs::StringConstPtr& msg1, std_msgs::StringConstPtr& msg2)
{
    ROS_INFO("HERE made it to handeler");
}

void setTest()
{
     Subscriber<std_msgs::String> j1_sub(n, "/SynchronizerTest1", 10);
     Subscriber<std_msgs::String> j2_sub(n, "/SynchronizerTest2", 10);
     TimeSynchronizer<std_msgs::String, std_msgs::String> sync(j1_sub, j2_sub, 10);
     sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&SynchronizerTest::handelerSynchronizerTest, this, _1, _2));
     ROS_INFO("Test set");
}


private:

 ros::NodeHandle n;

};  // Enodof Class



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "SynchronizerTest");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  int count = 0;

  SynchronizerTest sp;
  ros::Publisher pub1 = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("SynchronizerTest1", 10);
  ros::Publisher pub2 = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("SynchronizerTest2", 10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
     std_msgs::String msg;
     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << "hello world " << count;
     msg.data = ss.str();
     pub1.publish(msg);
     pub2.publish(msg);
     ros::spinOnce();
     loop_rate.sleep();
     ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84456/trying-to-write-test-pgm-for-timesync/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems you are trying to synchronize messages that do not have [std_msgs/Header](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) and thus time stamp as well. Without knowing the time stamp it is obviously impossible to synchronize anything.

Usually the message types that have a time stamp are called `xxxStamped` like, for example, [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-28**:
std_msgs::String is used in cases to send topics but then why no header. BTW I made changes and code still will not compile ...errors way to cryptic to understand. Will post updated code.